# Select data in netCDF file by variable

Tags: python, pandas, netcdf, netcdf4

I'm trying to extract weather data from a netCDF file based on a variable. The .nc file contains 14 variables and 2 dimensions. I would like to extract all the data of 14 variables related to the value of a the first variable. The data is from the dutch Metrological Institute and can be found [here](https://data.knmi.nl/datasets/etmaalgegevensKNMIstations/1?bbox=52.35,4.95,51.54,3.94&q=Neerslag).

**Data is load in Python using the netCDF4 module like this:**

```
import netCDF4 as nc
filename = r'path/file.nc'
dataset = nc.Dataset(filename)
```

**Printed variables and dimensions:**

```
dataset.variables.keys()
Out[67]: odict_keys(['station', 'time', 'lat', 'lon', 'DDVEC', 'FHVEC', 'TG', 'RH', 'UG', 'EV24', 'PG', 'iso_dataset', 'product', 'projection'])

dataset.dimensions.keys()
Out[68]: odict_keys(['station', 'time'])
```

I would like to extract the data for specific 'station' and put it in a pandas DataFrame to perform some calculations.

I tried something like this to extract the data however I know that this isn't the way netCDF files work but I can't figure out how.

```
df = dataset['344',:,:,:,:,:,:,:,:,0,0,0,0,0]
```

**Summary question:** is there a way to extract data for a certain station and put it in a pandas DataFrame?

## SOLUTION

```
import pandas as pd
import xarray as xr
# Open netCDF file and convert to dataframe
open_netcdf = xr.open_dataset(filename)
dataset = open_netcdf.to_dataframe()
# Select data from a tuple index based on station number: 391
df = dataset.iloc[dataset.index.get_level_values(0) == '391',:]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes there is a way. Investigate using [xarray](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/). It handles higher dimension data manipulation with ease. Filtering on one dimension is fairly trivial and then there is a .to_dataframe() method which will put your entire dataset into a pandas dataframe with multi-index.

Have a look [here](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/examples/weather-data.html) for an example of xarray being used with weather data.

Comment: Thanks, works perfect. I will add the solution code for future users.